# Deadlocking occurring in Mutex code?

Tags: c++, concurrency, deadlock

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with this segment of code? I've been studying it for a while and I still cannot see any dead-lock if there is one. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

```
Mutex mA;
Mutex mB;

Take(mA);
Take(mB);

DoSomething(); 

Release(mA); 
Release(mB);
```

Comment: it is better practice to release mB before mA.

Comment: A single thread can't really dead-lock. You have to say a bit more about what *else* you are running.

Comment: I was only given this piece of code to work with. @0x90 - Why's that?

Comment: Yes, releasing in the reverse order of acquiring is always "nice", but not required - as long as the next lock is released unconditionally (and preferrably soon after if there are other places that lock A then B - otherwise, you could cause unnecessary long loncking of A). As mentioned above, you do need TWO threads to deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

This code on it's own will not cause a problem. But if you have code that uses the reverse `Take(mB); Take(mA);` somewhere else, you can get a deadlock.

Comment: Hm.. thats definitely a possibility and I did consider that but I thought maybe there was something obviously wrong.

Comment: I would bump up this question but I don't have enough points. Thanks everyone.